# `do-release-upgrade` refuses to upgrade, although everything seems fine

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, package-management, upgrade

I have a good working 16.04 installed, everything fine, but as it is getting older, I would like to upgrade to the following LTS (18.04). So I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt update
(lots of stuff)

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Even added this:

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But then, when trying to upgrade, I get this:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Why is it asking to update ?
How can I solve this ?
Anything I can try to get more info ?

**Edit :** As suggested by @David, I disabled all the PPAs. Unfortunately, upgrade now starts but still fails. The command seems to check for packages, and terminates with:

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating the changes    
Could not calculate the upgrade     
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 
    
Restoring original system state    
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I did the automated bug report with `ubuntu-bug` (but I don't expect much on that side). Also checked the two files.

- `main.log` finishes with `Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'`
- `apt.log` (+4000 lines) shows a lot of broken dependencies, finishes with:

  Broken debhelper:amd64 Depends on dh-autoreconf [ amd64 ] < 11 -> 17 | 19~ubuntu18.04.1 > ( devel ) (>= 17~)
  Considering dh-autoreconf:amd64 8 as a solution to debhelper:amd64 13
  MarkKeep debhelper [ amd64 ] < 9.20160115ubuntu3 -> 11.1.6ubuntu2 | 12.1.1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 > ( devel ) FU=0
  Holding Back debhelper:amd64 rather than change dh-autoreconf:amd64
  Done

Any idea on what to do next?

---

Additional info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '18.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Full listing:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fuscated/codeblocks-nightly/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyrasis/imagemagick-jp2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-noprop/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mhier/libboost-latest/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/flightgear/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libheif/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release
  403  Forbidden [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-noprop/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/bionic-noprop/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: Do you have an PPA in the sources list?

Comment: Please add to your question above the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @David yes, lots of!

Comment: Remove them all and try again this is a common result with third party PPA present.

Comment: @user535733 Are you suggesting some failing ppa could be the cause? Because I indeed have some that reply with `does not have a Release file`, but I thought the added ppas get removed when upgrading.

Comment: Apt thinks that the list of packages is incomplete (due to the 404s), so it won't release-upgrade. Remove the dead PPAs.

Comment: Um, you have a LOT of PPAs and other non-Ubuntu sofware. @David is right -- best practice is to uninstall ALL of them, returning your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible, before a release-upgrade. That's the condition under which release-upgrades are tested. Maybe your system won't be broken by all the non-Ubuntu wrong-version packages on your system. But we have not tested that, so we don't know. If you are adding those sources because you want newer software, look into instead running a normal 6-month release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733, thanks for advice: `returning your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible`. Do you know how to do that? I already disabled all third-party PPAs, now `apt update` only reports 16 sources (all ubuntu.com based, so I guess its ok).